# Definition by commutation property on structures : continuity and where?

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, general-topology, measure-theory, operator-algebras

(This is very vague, so sorry if there are approximations)

I remember that one can define continuity as a commutation property of a function with the limit operation.
Structurally, i think it maps a filter of x to a filter of f(x)

Do you know similar examples in other areas, like probability, where such seemingly analytical properties can likewise be expressed as **commutation** on **structures** but are usually not so ?

I vaguely believe there was some in measure theory.